# Array to Loop through Cell Values Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have defined cells inside of two separate arrays. (i.e. `source_arr = ("B4","B5"...)` and `target_arr = ("B5","B6")`

I want to loop through both arrays and set the value of the target workbook cells equal to that of the source workbook cells. Right now it sets all the cells equal to one value.

```
 For i = LBound(source_array) To UBound(source_array)
For j = LBound(target_array) To UBound(target_array)
Data = source_workbook.Sheets("Questionnaire").Cells(source_array(i)).Value
target_workbook.Sheets("Questionnaire").Cells(target_array(j)).Value = Data
Next j
Next i
```

Comment: You may not be needing two arrays at all. Could you post a screenshot of your data?

Comment: maybe like `target_arr = array("B5","B6")`

Comment: If the arrays are isomorphic, only one loop is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to one loop.  And you want Range not Cells:

```
For i = LBound(source_array) To UBound(source_array)
    Data = source_workbook.Sheets("Questionnaire").Range(source_array(i)).Value
    target_workbook.Sheets("Questionnaire").Range(target_array(i)).Value = Data
Next i
```

Comment: I did manage to fix the Range part on my own as soon as I posted the question...*rolls eyes* However for some reason I was thinking I needed 2 loops! Such a bozo, I was over thinking it. Thanks for the help it works perfect.